# Classic ASP site page not responding, but does work if page is requested within the server

Tags: iis, asp-classic

We have a classic ASP site that is been hosted in IIS 7.5. I am looking at this weird behavior and I am trying to find a resolution for this. Now the problem with one of the many pages (not all pages) is http://website.com/admin/customers.asp

- If this page is requested from a browser within the server where the application is hosted, then everything works fine.
- If the page is requested ouside the server, i.e from some machine then the page never responds. and the wierd part here is that the IIS is not returing any status codes either, when looked via firebug...I see a staus of "(aborted)".
- Now here is a more interesting point, the page requested displays 7 customer records, however if I tweak the sql query to return 5 or less customers then everything works fine.

I have been working on this issue from past 1 day and so far figured that code is not a problem here, as it works in the server with the same data and database. Also, the page work fine if 5 or less records are returned...

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out with this problem...

Comment: Changing the code "fixes" the problem, yet you feel that the code is not a problem?  I think you should post code.  :-)

Comment: You should post code samples so that we can better assist you.  You state that your SQL statement does not return results if it has greater than 5 results so ensure you show what you're selecting.

Comment: no...the sql is returning data in both cases...I also tried remote debugging on the server...and in both cases the code is being run successfully...except that the request within the server gives a response, but the request made from outside the server is not getting a response...

Comment: When you use the browser on the server what URL do use `website.com` or `localhost`?  Is there a proxy server involved here?  is this a hosted server?  Are you accessing the server with a client on the same local network?  How big is the final response content?

Comment: I'm using website.com in both cases...

Comment: What do the logs show? Does it show a GET request to this page when you browse it externally?

Comment: Yes...a get request is been issued in both cases...i just tried creating a new website in one of our other servers and copied the same code there...and it works just fine...This just shows that there is something going on differently on the server box that i am using...

Comment: I would debug this by writing to plain text file. Create the file on the very top of the code, then append lines to it (e.g. "reached loop, starting to iterate" or "loop iteration number 2 - value is...") and check the file created to see where exactly the code hangs. If you need help implementing let me know and use `@` to notify e.g. if you start your comment with `@Sha` I will get notification and come back to check. None of the previous commentors came back because they were not notified of your own comments.

Comment: It works for 5 or less records seems to indicate that this may be due to too much data being returned to the browser. Can you measure the content-length for the most amount of records it works and post it here?

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the input...I am new to classic asp world, can you  help me out with this? Just as an FYI I did tried remote debugging and everything seems to be working fine...the database call is been made...data is been returned...and is processing as expected...the only glitch here is that the server is not responding with the data...and just aborts the page request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I've mentioned the problem was with the server that I was testing with and it turned out that we had to set the TCP/IP off load setting to disable(Via Broadcom client UI). 
Although, still need to figure out why we have to do this...

Thanks a lot for your time and suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, I do believe you have a problem between the internet and the machine where the website is hosted (proxy problems, firewalls, etc). However, since you stated that the problem is solved when you change a part of your code to show 5 results instead of 7, I think that you are iterating through a recordset without specifying the code for it to roll over:

rs.moveNext

Comment: ...the code does have rs.movenext...and as I mentioned earlier the code does not seem to be the problem here...it is more towards the configuration of IIS/Application/Website to serve response...

Answer (score 0):

As I've suggested in a comment, try debugging the issue by writing to text file and hopefully finding where the code get stuck. Sample code will be:

```vbs
<%
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO, oLogFile, myCounter
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oLogFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(Server.MapPath("customer_log.txt"))
oLogFile.WriteLine "BEGIN - " & Now()

'here comes your own code
'.....
'for example loop over some recordset
oLogFile.WriteLine "LOOP START - " & Now()
myCounter = 0
Do Until oRS.EOF
    oLogFile.WriteLine "Loop iteration #" & (myCounter + 1) & " Started - " & Now()
    '.....
    '.....
    '.....
    oLogFile.WriteLine "Loop iteration #" & (myCounter + 1) & " Finished - " & Now()
    myCounter = myCounter + 1
    oRS.MoveNext
Loop
oLogFile.WriteLine "LOOP END - " & Now()
oRS.Close
oLogFile.WriteLine "Recordset was closed - " & Now()
'.....


'after your code is finished:
oLogFile.WriteLine "END - " & Now()
oLogFile.Close
Set oLogFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
%>
```

Now after executing the page in a browser look for a file called "customer_log.txt" in the same directory as your ASP file and check its contents.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply...as it turned out...the issue was with the server and our System administrator figured out something with the network interface card on the Box...So all he did was to disable some TCP/IP specific setting in the broadcom client UI...